# Update DOM with fields from single firestore document

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to render a list to the DOM and then have the list elements update upon a snapshot from a single firestore document.

I have been able to accomplish this easily when listening to a collection snapshot and using the onChange() function, however, this function is not available when listening to a single document snapshot.

I had thought I had solved the issue with the following code:

```
const detailList = document.querySelector('#detail-list');

function loadDetail(){

// Render DOM
let name = document.createElement('li');
let description = document.createElement('li');
name.textContent = 'loading...'
description.textContent = 'loading...'
name.setAttribute('id', 'name');
description.setAttribute('id', 'description');
detailList.appendChild(name);
detailList.appendChild(description);


// Listen for document snapshot and update DOM
db.collection('1003')
.doc(localStorage.getItem('headingID'))
.collection('items')
.doc(localStorage.getItem('itemID'))
.onSnapshot(doc => {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = doc.data().name;
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = doc.data().description;

})
}
```

However when run the following error is thrown:

```
app.js:194 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.db.collection.doc.collection.doc.onSnapshot.doc [as next] (app.js:194)
    at next (firebase.js:1)
    at firebase.js:1
```

I am unsure of why this does not work as expected.

Comment: It seems like the document you're reading does not exist, leading to `doc.data()` being `null`/`undefined`. You might want to check with hard-coded values for the document IDs. If it works with those, the problem is in `localStorage.getItem('headingID')` or  `localStorage.getItem('itemID')`.

Comment: thanks for the help I tried all those issues beforehand and the problem wasn't solved, however after clearing browser cache and restarting the node it began working